# Get different random numbers on each thread using mpi, fortran

Tags: fortran, openmpi

I have a basic program which sends a message from thread to thread and replaces a character each time. My problem is that the random number generated in each thread is always the same. Here is my code:

```
if (me+1 == npe) then
        a = 0
    else
        a = me + 1
    end if

    if (me == 0) then
        b = npe-1
    else
        b = me-1
    end if

    if (me == 0) then
        call MPI_Send(msg, len(msg), MPI_CHARACTER, a, tag, comm, ierr)
    else
        call MPI_Recv(msg, len(msg), MPI_CHARACTER, b, tag, comm, stat, ierr)
        call random_number(u)
        j = FLOOR(14*u)
        msg(j:j) = "?"
        call MPI_Send(msg, len(msg), MPI_CHARACTER, a, tag, comm, ierr)
    end if
    if (me == 0) then
        call MPI_Recv(msg, len(msg), MPI_CHARACTER, b, tag, comm, stat, ierr)
end if
```

me = thread number, npe = total number of threads

everything works except for the random generated number. I tried using call random_seed(me) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you want each number to be different? Part of the strength of mpi is the communicators work on the same processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using [`RANDOM_SEED()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html) correctly. With a single (scalar) dummy argument, you are in fact querying `SIZE`, which

> specifies the minimum size of the arrays used with the PUT and GET arguments.

The correct usage is

```
call random_seed(put=seed)
```

where seed is an array (of size 12 on my machine/`gfortran`).

See [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html) for an example that you can adjust to your needs, i.e. use a different seed for each process. You could, e.g. choose a different prime in `pcg` according to the current rank. *Do not multiply with the rank* since this might give a zero seed, which is explicitly mentioned not to do in the reference...

Comment: So if anyone is interested: I kinda solved it by using first 
 call random_number(seed);
 seed = int(seed*1000)*(me+1) and then (seed is an array of size 12) in my code before i call the random number i used call random_seed(put=int(seed)). hope this helps and thank you!

Comment: @user3254126 If you have a solution there is no reason to not add that as a separate answer if it is sufficiently different from this one.  Reference this one, of course, if it helps with context.  Note, though, that with the approach you mention one has to be very careful about ensuring that there is reasonable entropy in the modified seed.